# Rodeo: ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels'

Tags: python, rodeo

I just start to use `Rodeo` with `Python 3.6.2`. But there is an error when importing `statsmodels` under Windows 10. Here is the script:

```
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
```

When highlight `import statsmodels.api as sm` and click `Run line`, there is an error:

```
>>> import statsmodels.api as sm
ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels'
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-6030a6549dc0> in <module>()
----> 1 import statsmodels.api as sm
ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels'
```

Then I downloaded the `statsmodels` from `Github` and installed it. Here is the output of `pip list`:

```
C:\Users\Documents\statsmodels-master\statsmodels-master>pip list
DEPRECATION: The default format will switch to columns in the future. You can use --format=(legacy|columns) (or define a format=(legacy|columns) in your pip.conf under the [list] section) to disable this warning.
Cython (0.26)
numpy (1.13.1)
pandas (0.20.3)
patsy (0.4.1)
pip (9.0.1)
python-dateutil (2.6.1)
pytz (2017.2)
scipy (0.19.1)
setuptools (28.8.0)
six (1.10.0)
statsmodels (0.8.0)
```

The output shows that `statsmodels 0.8.0` is installed. But there is still importing error. It seems that the `Rodeo` has difficulty to see `statsmodels`.

UPDATE:

Here is the output of `print(sys.pth)` in `Rodeo`. There is a path for the `statsmodels`.

```
>>> print(sys.path)
['', 'C:\\Python36\\Scripts', 'c:\\python36\\lib\\site-packages\\statsmodels-0.8.0-py3.6-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\Python36', 'C:\\Python36\\python36.zip', 'C:\\Python36\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python36\\lib', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\patsy-0.4.1-py3.6.egg', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\pandas-0.20.3-py3.6-win-amd64.egg', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\six-1.10.0-py3.6.egg', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\pytz-2017.2-py3.6.egg', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\python_dateutil-2.6.1-py3.6.egg', 'C:\\Python36\\lib\\site-packages\\IPython\\extensions', 'C:\\Users\\JunC\\.ipython']
```

Comment: did you do `pip install statsmodels`?

Comment: Installed with `python setup.py install` under `statsmodels`

Comment: Tried `pip install statsmodels` and returns  all `requirement already satisfied`

Comment: I'm not too familiar with that, but it might be that the package is not installed in a path listed in the `PYTHONPATH`? You can `import sys` then `print(sys.path)` to see where Python can reach packages, then check where the `statsmodels` folder is.

Comment: `Arther Spoon`, I just updated with the output of `sys.path`. Is it possible that the `Rodeo` is using its own python which is not the 3.6.2 I installed? I added the C:\python36 and `statsmodels.egg` to `PYTHONPATH` and those paths are not showing in the output here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I solved it by adding the path to statsmodels to rodes>preferences>environment variables. In my case the path was "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\pkgs".

Answer (score 0):

You might not have latest version of python2. Either update it, or use python3 instead.

> To use python 3, use pip3 instead of pip. So run the following:
>
> `pip3 install statsmodels`